# How to log the x-forwarded-by from nginx in spring-boot/tomcat (IPv4/IPv6)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, nginx, load-balancing

How do I log the Client's real ip address from nginx in tomcat/spring-boot via CommonsRequestLoggingFilter for both IPv4 and IPv6?

I have nginx setup to reverse proxy tomcat (via spring-boot) and I have had limited success with spring-boot's `server.use-forward-headers: true` option. It works with IPv4 addresses; however, it still logs 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 (nginx) for IPv6 addresses. This is a problem because by default nginx and tomcat both bind to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses so nginx will forward to tomcat requests over one or the other randomly.

Example Logging statements:

```
Before request [uri=/membershiprequest;client=128.250.87.102;user=admin]
Before request [uri=/activity;client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;user=admin]
```

Ideally, both should say:

```
Before request [uri=/membershiprequest;client=128.250.87.102;user=admin]
Before request [uri=/activity;client=128.250.87.102;user=admin]
```

In both cases, nginx is including the `x-forwarded-by` header:

IPv4

```
18:43:14.816532 IP 127.0.0.1.56540 > 127.0.0.1.8180:
........GET /activity HTTP/1.0
Host: test.local.org
X-Real-IP: 128.250.87.102
X-Forwarded-For: 128.250.87.102
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

IPv6

```
18:43:14.817830 IP6 ::1.37684 > ::1.8180: 
........GET /membershiprequest HTTP/1.0
Host: test.local.org
X-Real-IP: 128.250.87.102
X-Forwarded-For: 128.250.87.102
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

Comment: When boot uses code sleuth it needs to do something similar: transport headers end to end. Perhaps you can find a solution there.